# Не выходит изменить размер квадратов в фиксированном поле, исходя из количества всех его клеток

Tags: java, массивы, javafx

У меня есть квадратное поле, которое я разбиваю на клетки, но размер этих клеток фиксирован и при небольшом количестве строк и столбцов на поле, остается много пустого пространства. Как создавать поле с клетками, размер которых будет изменяться вместе с размером его строками и столбцами?

```
    void repanit(){
pane.getChildren().clear();
boolean[][] b = game.getPole();
for(int i=1;i<=rows;i++)
for(int j=1;j<=cols;j++) {
Rectangle pole = (i==1&&j==1) ? new Rectangle(j, i, 430/cols, 430/rows) : new Rectangle(j*(430/cols), i*(430/rows), 430/cols, 430/rows);
pole.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
pane.getChildren().add(pole);
}
}
```

Первый квадрат поля рисуется правильно и с нужным размером, остальные не следуют за ним,а разбросаны по полю. Пример для поля 3х3[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: изменил `for(int i=1;i<=rows;i++)
for(int j=1;j<=cols;j++)` на `for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)` , теперь не рисуется только центральный  квадрат

Comment: `Rectangle pole = new Rectangle(j*(430/cols), i*(430/rows), 430/cols, 430/rows);` Кажется, получилось